# Combination of different types of nouns results in which pronoun?

Tags: nouns, pronouns

When I combine a noun that refers to a person and another noun, do I use whom or which? Like in the following simple example.

> Jesus was crucified because of Caiaphas and the Roman Empire, whose (/which?) power he undermined.

I know this is not a perfect sentence, but you get the idea? Caiaphas is a person so we use who, but the Roman Empire is not so we use which, however in a sentence we can only put one. Which one is it? I think it should be the latter for better flow.

Comment: Your grasp of theology might be criticised in some quarters. Anyhow, 'whose' - see here: [Whose used for inanimate objects](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/whose-used-for-inanimate-objects)

Comment: ... Though here, 'the Roman Empire' is virtually an honarary sentient referent (like 'family' or 'staff'), and 'whose' is doubly licensed.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Isn't there a strong argument that 'quarters' should be capitalised?

Comment: Depends how holy you think people like William Tyndale and Saint Augustine are.

Comment: ok if it was WHICH vs WHO, e.g, "<Proper Name> and <government> which didn't want him to lead people"

Comment: The only possessive relative pronoun is _whose_. Use it wherever a possessive is required.